# AdminLTE 3 Datatables styling isn't fully applied

Tags: css, datatables, adminlte

I am using AdminLTE 3 dashboard template for my project. When I try to use it's datatables plugin, not all styles are applied. [image]

JS and CSS files are linked, the table content is also valid. But in the example on the official site, the table looks more pretty. E.g. the search bar is with rounded borders, and number of entries selection is a bit wider.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] - for example as a Fiddle, or similar?

Comment: Also take a look at the [`dom` option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom), as that gives you some additional control over the positioning and styling of the elements you have highlighted in your question.

Comment: In the fiddle it works. I think something is wrong with bootstrap. First, it didn't even show icons, now when I added bootstrap css file manually, even if I had one, it showed icons.

Comment: Make sure you are using the recommended downloads for integrating DataTables with Bootstrap - see the examples [listed here](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/) - and also see the main [downloads](https://datatables.net/download/index) page.